# select next rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I have more records in my database. so I want to select first 10,000 record. Then i have to continue the selection from next records means next 10,001 to till some values. How to put query here?

Any idea means helpful to me.

Comment: "I have more than 70,000 records" - Congratulations! Soon you'll be in the 100K rows club!

Comment: Search for "efficient paging"

Comment: Mr. Mitch wheat don't play comedy roles here..You have to refer faq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to select from rows 10,001

To get the next 1000 rows you could do:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM
TABLE
WHERE ID >= 10001
```

Or simply apply an `AND` clause in the `WHERE` which would return rows 10,001 - 15,001:

```
SELECT * FROM
TABLE
WHERE ID >= 10001 AND ID <= 15001
```

Answer (score 5):

If you havent ID row in your table, or ID isn't IDENTITY, you can use ROW_NUMBER function like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Products.ProductID) as 'rownbr', Products.ProductID
FROM Products
ORDER BY Products.ProductID
```

and then just use WHERE clause like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Products.ProductID) as 'rownbr', Products.ProductID
FROM Products
WHERE rownbr BETWEEN 10000 and 20000
ORDER BY Products.ProductID
```

Comment: what the problem? people recommend him use WHERE ID >= 10001. But I dont see, where did he say, that he got any IDENTITY column in hos table. and (@count - 10000) returns him all entries after first 10k, not "10,001 to till some values"

Comment: no one people say i have identity column. This is the common thing. If they don't have identity column means they will mention. Because it is different.Just understand the flow.

Comment: you can also make select %some_date% into my_new_table from ...  And you will get new table with lot of data you need, but w/o identity column. This way you can use ROW_NUMBER.

Answer (score 1):

First 10,000 Records and then rest of records;

```
SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM table ORDER BY Id
DECLARE @count int;
SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM table);
SELECT TOP (@count - 10000) * FROM table ORDER BY Id DESC;
```

Comment: What's going on here?

Comment: what?what is going here?

Comment: Actually you select first 10000 row then select from 10001 to row count

Comment: yes. correct. what is the problem with this?

Comment: Sorry for the vague comment. The second example `SELECT TOP (COUNT(*) - 10000)` won't work as I don't think you can have expressions in TOP clauses. But, even if it did; if you had 70,000 rows...it would  return the top 60,000 - wouldn't it?

Comment: try edited solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to following link for solution-

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/6fdeb5f0-b705-4e40-a98b-6dd25539e92d